# OperationTimedOutException in gremlin and janusgraph while connecting it with scylla running in docker-container

Tags: cassandra, gremlin, janusgraph, gremlin-server, scylla

I tried to implement scylla with janusgraph, but  received operation timeout exception.
I also tried to implement cassandra with janusgraph and run successfully.

I am running scylladb in docker-container and I was running cassandra on my local machine.
I am not sure running in doccker-container will be the reason.

In cassandra, after certain operation it stop prompting anything on screen while running it using cassandra -f but in the case  of scylla it is continously promting something like following. I don't know why it is.

```
INFO  2021-07-06 04:40:24,566 [shard 0] compaction - [Compact system_schema.columns 4786c960-de14-11eb-b4f5-03c308428361] Compacting [/var/lib/scylla/data/system_schema/columns-24101c25a2ae3af787c1b40ee1aca33f/md-116-big-Data.db:level=0:origin=memtable, /var/lib/scylla/data/system_schema/columns-24101c25a2ae3af787c1b40ee1aca33f/md-112-big-Data.db:level=0:origin=compaction, ]
INFO  2021-07-06 04:40:24,794 [shard 3] schema_tables - Schema version changed to 0b21a303-c053-3c4c-9fba-85f3bdd54894
```

The timeout error I am receiving is following

```
 com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.OperationTimedOutException: [/127.0.0.1:9042] Timed out waiting for server response
    at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.OperationTimedOutException.copy(OperationTimedOutException.java:43)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.OperationTimedOutException.copy(OperationTimedOutException.java:25)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.DriverThrowables.propagateCause(DriverThrowables.java:35)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture.getUninterruptibly(DefaultResultSetFuture.java:293)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractSession.execute(AbstractSession.java:58)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.cql.CQLKeyColumnValueStore.initializeTable(CQLKeyColumnValueStore.java:236)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.cql.CQLKeyColumnValueStore.<init>(CQLKeyColumnValueStore.java:161)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.cql.CQLStoreManager.lambda$openDatabase$14(CQLStoreManager.java:420)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1705)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.cql.CQLStoreManager.openDatabase(CQLStoreManager.java:420)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.keycolumnvalue.KeyColumnValueStoreManager.openDatabase(KeyColumnValueStoreManager.java:43)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.Backend$5.apply(Backend.java:611)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.Backend$5.apply(Backend.java:606)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.Backend.getLocker(Backend.java:209)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.locking.consistentkey.ExpectedValueCheckingStoreManager.openDatabase(ExpectedValueCheckingStoreManager.java:64)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.Backend.initialize(Backend.java:237)
    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.configuration.GraphDatabaseConfiguration.getBackend(GraphDatabaseConfiguration.java:1360)
    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.database.StandardJanusGraph.<init>(StandardJanusGraph.java:146)
    at org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory.open(JanusGraphFactory.java:161)
    at org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory.open(JanusGraphFactory.java:132)
    at org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory.open(JanusGraphFactory.java:79)
    at org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory$open.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:115)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:127)
    at groovysh_evaluate.run(groovysh_evaluate:3)
    at groovysh_evaluate$run.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at groovysh_evaluate$run.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Interpreter.evaluate(Interpreter.groovy:81)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Evaluator$evaluate.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Groovysh.execute(Groovysh.groovy:201)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.GremlinGroovysh.super$3$execute(GremlinGroovysh.groovy)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor28.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:101)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1217)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:144)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.GremlinGroovysh.execute(GremlinGroovysh.groovy:83)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Shell.leftShift(Shell.groovy:120)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Shell$leftShift$1.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.ShellRunner.work(ShellRunner.groovy:93)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.super$2$work(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:101)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1217)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:144)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuper0(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:164)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.work(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy:138)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PlainObjectMetaMethodSite.doInvoke(PlainObjectMetaMethodSite.java:43)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:190)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:58)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:160)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.ShellRunner.run(ShellRunner.groovy:57)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.super$2$run(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:101)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1217)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:144)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuper0(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:164)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.run(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy:97)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:234)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.Console.<init>(Console.groovy:168)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:234)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.Console.main(Console.groovy:502)
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.OperationTimedOutException: [/127.0.0.1:9042] Timed out waiting for server response
    at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler$SpeculativeExecution.onTimeout(RequestHandler.java:979)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$ResponseHandler$1.run(Connection.java:1605)
    at io.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer$HashedWheelTimeout.expire(HashedWheelTimer.java:672)
    at io.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer$HashedWheelBucket.expireTimeouts(HashedWheelTimer.java:747)
    at io.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer$Worker.run(HashedWheelTimer.java:472)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

Answer (score 4):

In the timeout error you posted - see:
`OperationTimedOutException: [/127.0.0.1:9042]`

If you are using Scylla on docker, you should use the container IP (and only on Linux), on Mac you wouldn't be able to access the container from the host.

Comment: I am using linux, When I was using container ip i.e. 172.17.0.2 , then I was getting error No host found exception. Then I tried to do port forwarding, and then I receive operation time out exception. Then after a lot of brainstorming I found that I was able to connect but the scylladb was not able to serve my request, then I tried to pass username and password and this works. A keyspace with the name Janusgraph (which is the default for Janusgraph) has been  created successfully.

Comment: But now I am facing another issue. The problem of Data persistence. I have created the nodes and edges. But after shutting down docker and my system next day when I open both , I found data was not there. There was no any node. I don't know what mistakes I have done?